# Problem with chart generation in SkiaChart

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, charts, backend

In the mvc project on the back, it is necessary to form a graph image in the form of an array of bytes according to the given data. I'm trying to do it via `SkiaChart`
I create a chart like this:

```
public byte[] GetBarChart(PrintChart printChart)
{
    var labels = printChart.Dataset.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
    var values = printChart.Dataset.Select(x => (float)x.Value).ToList();

    var chart = new BarChart(labels, values);
    chart.ChartColor = new SKColor(127, 210, 172);
    var wrapper = new Chart<BarChart>(new List<BarChart>() { chart });
    var info = new SKImageInfo(1000, 1000);
    using (var surface = SKSurface.Create(info))
    {
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

        var converter = new Converter(SKRect.Create(800, 800), 0, 0);
        var canvasWrapper = new CanvasWrapper(canvas, SKRect.Create(800, 800), 10, 400, 400, false, false, 5, 20, converter);
        wrapper.Plot(canvasWrapper);
        var image = surface.Snapshot();
        
        using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100))
        {
            return data.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the dimensions right. The chart either goes outside the grid or is drawn outside the grid at all

I tried resizing `Converter`, `CanvasWrapper`. But I couldn't find the right one.